# Writing a function which computes metric for a data-frame with conditions

Tags: r

Consider a data-frame of the following nature:

```
 x y  z label
 1 3  2  a
 2 4  4  b
 3 8  5  c
 4 5  6  a
 5 1  8  f
```

I need to write a function which picks a given observation and computes the euclidean metric for all observations using that initial observation as a reference point conditional on the observation being part of a given label.

So calling the function would look a bit like this:

```
f(reference obs, label="letter")
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: I tried using the dist() function but its extremely redundant since it computes distances between all elements, plus I have no idea how to use it with a if() statement. One could use a for cycle but I 'am sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You can use the dist() function to compute the distance between only two points, for example `dist(rbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)))`. Then loop through all the observations with the correct label and compute the distance to your reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=T, text="
x y z label
1 3 2 a
2 4 4 b
3 8 5 c
4 5 6 a
5 1 8 f")

f <- function(refObs, label) {
  dist <- vector()
  for (i in which(df$label==label))   
    dist <- c(dist, sqrt(sum((refObs - df[i,1:3])^2)))
  return(dist)
}

f(c(1,3,2), "a")
# [1] 0.000000 5.385165
```

Comment: Better to use d <- c(d, dist(rbind (refObs, df[i,1:dim]) , method ="euclidean") ) thought: more powerful, allows computation with different metrics and dimensions